# Django new views not being added?

Tags: python, django

I started going through tut but then got stuck on the page. 
[tutorial page 3 - django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/)

I exactly followed the tut to the point where it asks to goto localhost:8000/polls/.
There starts the problem, it is not working, states an error[image]

Please, tell how to correct the error.

Comment: add polls url pattern to urls.py

Answer (score 0):

That page is a `404 page not found`. This suggests to me that you have either not configured your URL's correctly or it's missing.

/project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

Where polls.urls points to your app URL at `/polls/urls.py`

So now in your polls/url.py add the index as described.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view